# Why didn't Vince have any confidence in Thomas?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In *Maze Runner: The Death Cure* (2018), Thomas selects a point on the map to reach it and save Minho. This causes Vince to scold him:

> Thomas: It's a few hundred miles. Based on the railways, everything that Aris told us, that's gotta be where they're headed. That's where they're taking  Minho. We take everyone who can fight. Follow the roads where we can. We can make it back within a week.
>
> Vince: A week? It took us six months to get here.We got over 100 kids here now. We can't just hang out here forever after what we just pulled.  **You wanna wander off to some random point on the map. You don't even know what's there**.

Why didn't Vince have any confidence in Thomas?